# Implement a function that returns True if the given string matches the given wildcard pattern, False otherwise

Tags: javascript, wildcard, contains

Implement a function that returns True if the given string matches the given wildcard pattern, False otherwise.

Allowed to use built in `split()`, `indexOf()`, `startsWith()` and `endsWith()`.

It is very similar to the last one I did but I still can't seem to get the hang of it. Here's what I have so far

```js
function matches(text, pattern) {
    var x = pattern.split("*");
    var y = (text.indexOf(x[0]) !== -1);
    for (i = 0; i< x.length; i++){
        if (y) {
            y = (text.indexOf(x[i]) !== -1);
        }
    }
    return y;
}

console.log(matches("lord of the rings", "lord*rings")); // Expected: True
console.log(matches("lord of the rings", "Lord*rings")); // Expected: False
console.log(matches("lord of the rings", "l*o*t*r")); // Expected: False
console.log(matches("lord of the rings", "l*o*t*r*s")); // Expected: True
console.log(matches("lord of the rings", "lord*")); // Expected: True
console.log(matches("lord of the rings", "*rings")); // Expected: True
console.log(matches("lord of the rings", "*the*")); // Expected: True
console.log(matches("lord of the rings", "*")); // Expected: True
console.log(matches("lord of the rings", "*z*")); // Expected: False
```

What I am trying to do is isolate the words and then check each one of them, and if all of them are present then I return `true` or if at least one of them isn't I return `false`. But something goes wrong and I don't quite understand what.

Would appreciate a solution, or feedback to my code, please keep it fairly simple.
Thank you!

Comment: *"But something goes wrong"* is far too vague to be useful. I will note that your current code doesn't do anything to check that the individual parts are in the **order** specified by the wildcard string.

Comment: And let me say we are not here to do your homework for you ;)

Comment: Lelio what does that supposed to mean? I don't know if you can see it in my profile but I code just for fun and asking this simply because I am stuck and was beating my head against a wall for a while now. This isnt because I have a coding class and this is my homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
function matches(text, pattern) {
    while (text.length) {
        if (text[0] !== pattern[0] && pattern[0] !== '*')
            return false;

        text = text.slice(1);

        var wordAfterWildcard = pattern.split('*')[1];

        if (pattern[0] !== '*' || wordAfterWildcard && text.startsWith(wordAfterWildcard))
            pattern = pattern.slice(1);
    }
    return !(pattern && pattern.replace('*', ''));
}
```

// I did your homework because I'm a crazy person. not because of u.
// enjoy...

Comment: Heeey sorry just look at the answer I gave Lelio I literally just typed it in.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry :)